# Estimate Odds Ratio

Tags: statistics

I need help this question:
According to poll results released by the Pew Research Center (www.people-press.org) in 2010, when adults in the United States were asked whether there is solid evidence that the average temperature on earth has been getting warmer over the past few decades, the estimated odds of a yes response for a Democrat was 2.96 times higher than for an Independent and it was 2.08 times higher for an Independent than for a Republican. Find the estimated odds ratio between opinion on global warming and whether one i a Democrat or a Republican. Interpret.

Here is my answer : 2.96/2.08 = 1.42 The estimate odds of a yes response for a Democrat was 1.42 times higher than for a Republican. Is is right? Please help. Thanks

Comment: if the answer solves your question you can accept it by clicking the tick

Answer (score 1):

Let $D$ = democrat, $I$ = independent, $R$ = republican. Or rather, $D$ = the odds that a democrat responds 'yes' etc.. From the question we have that:

$$
D = 2.96  I
$$

and

$$
I = 2.08 R
$$

and so:

$$
D = 2.96 I = 2.96 (2.08 R) = 6.16 R
$$

So a democrat is 6.16 times more likely to vote yes than a republican.